# Is there a way to create custom pathways using the Google Maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps, path

I need to create custom pathways using the Google Maps API V3 for a map of a campus

I know I could create pre-determined paths based on checkpoints that I input, but I need to be able to make it so that a user using the map I've created can click from one side of the campus to the other, and have the option to either follow roads/sidewalks, OR to go THROUGH BUILDINGS.

Is this possible, and if so, can I get some assistance, or a link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone sees this and wants a relevant response, one is given here: [Custom routes/paths/roads on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741808/custom-routes-paths-roads-on-google-maps)